# Ubuntu 22.04 KVM Installation

Tags: server, system-installation

I'm following this procedure: https://linuxhint.com/install-kvm-ubuntu-22-04/

When I apply the netplan for the yaml file I get an error:

```
sudo netplan apply
Failed to reload network settings: No such file or directory
```

Debug of netplan yields:

```
netplan --debug generate
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: starting new processing pass
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: starting new processing pass
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: br0: adding new route
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: enp1s0f1: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: Configuration is valid
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: enp6s0f0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: Configuration is valid
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: br0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: Configuration is valid
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: enp1s0f0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: Configuration is valid
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: Configuration is valid
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: enp6s0f1: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:20463): DEBUG: 23:06:06.988: Configuration is valid
ERROR: cannot create file /run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service: Failed to create file “/run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service.CLDTV1”: Permission denied
```

Any idea what is causing the issue?

Comment: Just install qemu-system-x86, that will pick up kvm do what's necessary for networking.  Your link starts with installing packages like qemu-kvm that don't even exist on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your netplan config file?  Seems like the parser is happy with the yaml but netplan not so much.

Also, KVM will start and run without the addition of the bridge and if you only want local VM's for a bit of testing you don't need it.  The KVM install on ubuntu gives you a local NAT network out of the box with no effort required.  So if you want to test the rest of the install you can revert the netplan file and give it a shot..